# 20.04.1, Application Folder Window Size

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell

In Ubuntu 20.04.1, GNOME, I have moved applications in the "show applications" window into my own categories.

I notice that in the application "folders", it only shows 4 across and 3 down. So, if you have more than 12 applications in a application folder, you have to scroll down.

Is there any way to either adjust the size of that sub folder window, or, a way to change the size of the huge icons in those sub folders windows so more would fit. I can't find a tuning value anywhere yet.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way/manipulation would be to install the extension [more-columns-in-applications-view](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1305/more-columns-in-applications-view/) and edit the `extension.js` file to replace the `function setNbColumns(setting)` content with below content.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function setNbColumns(setting) {

    if (!injections['_init']) {
        injections['_init'] = injectToFunction(AppDisplay.BaseAppView.prototype, '_init', function(){
            this._grid._minColumns = setting;
        });
    }

    let appdisplayView = Main.overview.viewSelector.appDisplay._views;
    for (let i = 0; i < appdisplayView.length; i++) {
        appdisplayView[i].view._grid._minColumns = setting;
    }

    let folderIconsList = Main.overview.viewSelector.appDisplay._views[1].view.folderIcons;
    if (folderIconsList) {
        // Old GS versions only
        folderIconsList.forEach(function(i){
            i.view._grid._minColumns = setting;
        });
    }

}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please note that if you have ideas to use this extension for its original purpose, you may not achieve what you are looking for. This is just a workaround targeted for the Question only.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Works beautifully. Probably overridden on every extension update, we'll see. Thanks! It does disable the intended use of the extension, but, I don' care or need that functionality.

Comment: Hi just renaming the extension in proper way will get away from updates..